# Making entire background image clickable

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make my code, which is just a page with the entire background an image into a clickable link. Thus wherever the mouse hovers over, it can click to redirect the user elsewhere.

Here's my code so far:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/yesno.png); 
    background-size: cover;
}

<body>
<a href="manw-manb.html" title="manw-manb" id="body"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: try to put 'body ' tag inside the 'a' tag , but i am sure you will not like the result ,

Comment: I can't click on the background to be redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use the `<img>` element in this instance, and wrap the entire thing in your `<a>`, which will achieve the same thing without any JavaScript. This is probably better, since you currently just have an empty anchor element, which isn't good. Be sure to add an `alt` attribute to your `<img>` for accessibility purposes.

```
<a href="your/path/here">
     <img src="*whatever your css url was*" alt="description of your image" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your script tag. and remove the anchor tag

```
function fn(){
window.location.href = 'manw-manb.html';
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);
```